# What does "so removed" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "**therefore, when Emerging market debt is removed, Norges Bank really cannot afford to lose such a significant source of demand**"?

Norges Bank "is a huge player in global bonds, and as such, many sovereign wealth funds follow the allocation lead of Norway," said Nicholas Glinsman, chief investment officer at financial advisory firm Evo Capital. "Emerging market debt is one asset class **so removed**, and it really cannot afford to lose such a significant source of demand."

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/09/06/the-worlds-biggest-sovereign-wealth-fund-wants-to-change-its-strategy--and-the-effects-could-be-global.html

Comment: It either means "**very different from**" or "**distant from**".

Comment: You have to read more carefully @Haile. "The [Norges benchmark index] fund can continue to invest in the currencies and segments that were recommended to be **removed** from the benchmark index - such as emerging market currencies, the Japanese yen, the Canadian dollar and the Swiss franc."

Comment: @SovereignSun: It could mean ***very distant*** in other contexts, but in OP's specific context it doesn't (there, it's equivalent to *removed (written off) **in such a way***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeh, I have reviewed this already and you are absolutely right.

Comment: This morning I woke up realizing that to refer to "Emerging market debt" as an *actor* is indeed rather strange, and that strangeness in part explains why @haile did not take *debt* as the antecedent of **it**. "Emerging market debt" is being vaguely personified here. What is actually meant is "Indebted countries which are located in emerging markets and are seeking to issue bonds on their debt cannot really afford to lose such a significant purchaser of debt bonds as the Norges Bank is."  Who else will take their bonds if that bank stops buying them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emerging market debt, which is one of the asset classes Norges Bank plans to remove from its benchmark index fund, cannot afford to lose such a significant source of demand for it as the Norges Bank is, as the bank is  "a huge player in global bonds".